# Text clip by backround color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im creating a full screen intro page. 
I need to create a drop down columns witch changes background color from dark to light and reveals a content. But I need that main title (text) clipping to background color - in process of animation it changes.

[image]
On the light background text should be black

There's the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/7qLa3f8s/)

SCSS

```
.header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;

  .overlay{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    .col{
      flex: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: black;
    }
  }

  .content{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    > div{
      flex: 1;
    }

    .title{
      position: relative;
      color: white;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .posts{
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;

      a{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: lightblue;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout(function () {

    $(".overlay .col").each(function (i) {
        var col = $(this);
      setTimeout(function () {

        if(!col.hasClass('animated')){
            col.addClass('animated');
            col.slideUp(500);
        }

      }, 150 * i);
    });

  }, 500);

});
```

Also there's is some glitch between animations, I wanted to know why this happening

**RESOLVED**
add to `.header`

```
background: white;
```

and to `.header .content .title {`

```
mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
```

NEW [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/7qLa3f8s/38/)

Comment: Just to confirm, what you want is when the stripes animation is complete/is happening, the h1 text should be in black color. Am I right?

Comment: @AKNair While animation happening - one part of text dark when background light and opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you edit your title css so it shows:

```
.title{
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  color:white;
  z-index: 3;

}
```

Note: this might not work for older versions of IE - let me know how that works out for you, cheers.

See more about the mix-blend-mode property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

**Update:** Here's a modified fiddle showing the animation wrapped over the columns rather than animate per column - https://jsfiddle.net/kqyno63x/

Comment: you missed to add background property for `.header`, but no it works! updated question!

Comment: Apologies for not addressing the animation glitch, where you're using the animation anchoring per column, would it not be easier for you (and maybe the browser) to render the animation anchoring on a single div wrapped around the columns or is that not something you desired? If I get time I'll see if I can present this in a revision of the fiddle later.

Answer (score 0):

You can set color and opacity for text that you want to display in background. please refer below code. Also please find fiddle link for same.

```
.textBackground{
 color:black;
 opacity: 0.3;
}
<h1 class="textBackground">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
```